# How to run two threads simultaneously while sharing their values?

Tags: python, multithreading, queue

I need to run two threads. The first one is a sensor, the second one is motor. 
I need to run those two threads in parallel with two different delay times and I need to communicate between them. This is my try code. here the motor thread runs only once and print

This is the code

```
from queue import Queue
from threading import Thread
import time

def sensor(numbers,q):
    for n in numbers:
        q.put(n*n)
        print (n*n)
        time.sleep(1)  # Add some delay here

def motor():
    a=q.get()
    if (a<10):
        print("good")
        time.sleep(2)  # Add some delay here
    else:
        print ("bad")
        time.sleep(2)  # Add some delay here


if __name__=="__main__":
    numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
    q= Queue()

    p= Thread(target=sensor , args = (numbers,q))
    r= Thread(target = motor)
    p.start()
    r.start()
```

`
this is the results i got

```
1
good
4
9
16
25
36
49
64
```

i need to get good or bad comment after each number.

Comment: So what is the problem and what is the question ?

Comment: i need to get good or bad comment after print each number although the treads have two different delay times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `motor` calls the method `q.get()` which returns only one item from the queue so that normal it prints only one result.

You have to iterate over the queue until it is empty

```
def motor():
    while not q.empty():
        a=q.get()
        if (a<10):
            print("good")
            ...
```

Comment: Thank you it worked.  can i empty the queue inside the while loop and reuse?

Comment: I think this only works because the `motor` thread is processing entries in the queue slower than they're being added. Generally speaking, If that wasn't the case, it would be possible for the queue to be empty, but only temporarily (until the producer task put something else in it)—so simply checking whether it's empty isn't a reliable approach.

Comment: Yes you are true, I lack all details, just looping with `while True` works also

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would do it. First, the `motor` task should be a loop so it retrieves more than one item from the `Queue` when it runs. To tell it when to stop, a special value (marker) can be put into the queue to indicate to the task to do so (break out of the loop and quit).

After doing that, you can just wait until it finishes by calling its `join()` method.

This is what I mean:

```
from queue import Queue
from threading import Thread
import time

def sensor(numbers, q):
    for n in numbers:
        q.put(n*n)
        print(n*n)
        time.sleep(1)  # Add some delay here

    q.put(None)  # End marker.

def motor():
    while True:
        a = q.get()
        if a is None:  # End marker?
            break  # Quit.
        if a < 10:
            print("good")
            time.sleep(2)  # Add some delay here
        else:
            print ("bad")
            time.sleep(2)  # Add some delay here


if __name__=="__main__":
    numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
    q = Queue()

    p = Thread(target=sensor, args=(numbers, q))
    r = Thread(target=motor)
    p.start()
    r.start()
    r.join()  # Wait for consumer thread to finish.
    print('done')
```